# Need ideas for effective and streamlined JS application development

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

I have been working on a JS-heavy web application. Due to the nature of the network the application will be running on, I would like to minimize the amount of traffic between server and client, and would like to run as much as possible on the client side. This application is much larger than anything else I have written before, and I am really struggling with streamlining my development and, more importantly, testing.

First and foremost, I am not a developer, so I am not trained nor am I familiar with different development techniques, but I learn as I go.

Lots of trial and error, Stack Overflow reading, and more trial and error. This causes lots of page reloading, which means I am back at the first page of the application and have to click through a bunch of screens just to get to the part I am working on. Over and over and over again. All. Day. Long.

How can I speed this up, and maybe automate that? I know there is Selenium WebDriver, but that seems a bit too complicated for what I need, plus there is some drag and drop involved in the beginning of the app, and from what I understand Selenium can't do that.

Please help me come up with a better approach to this. In  this day an age, there has to be something that would help me. Some kind of a way to feed data to an application, so I can immediately get to the point i need, without starting from the first page. I just have no idea what I am searching for or how to phrase my searches so I don't get the same useless results from Google.

P.S. Developing on OS X, so Windows tools won't really work for me. Plus majority of the users will be on Macs.``

Comment: You could code your app so that it uses pushState to modify the url as you navigate through the app, allowing you to refresh the page and get directly to the page that you were at before refreshing. This would of course mean making the the app recognize said urls.

Comment: You may also want to try some unit testing.

Comment: Kevin, thank you! This maybe what I am looking for! Would this allow me to reload a single "page", preserving DOM data somehow? A comment on that page has also linked me to history.js, which may help me too.

Comment: @dqhendricks: I looked into that, but that seems a bit too... involved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you are not interested in windows tools for development, I would recomend John Papa's series on SPA ( single page application ) development. It covers litteraly all topics on TDD of SPA and would no doubt give you a lot of ideas with your project.
Just skip parts on web.api usage and consider yourself creating REST service using any other tools you are familiar with.

http://www.johnpapa.net/building-single-page-apps-with-knockout-jquery-and-web-api-ndash-the-story-begins/

Chapters included in the series:

- Part 1 – The Story Begins (What is the Code Camper SPA?)
- Part 2 – Client Technologies
- Part 3 – Server Technologies (the Data Layer)
- Part 4 – Serving JSON with ASP.NET Web API
- Part 5 – HTML 5 and ASP.NET Web Optimization
- Part 6 – JavaScript Modules
- Part 7 – MVVM and KnockoutJS
- Part 8 – Data Services on the Client
- Part 9 – Navigation, Transitions, Storage and Messaging
- Part 10 – Saving, Change Tracking, and Commanding
- Part 11- Responsive Design and Mobility

Comment: Thank you! This seems pretty relevant. I will definitely take a look at this.

Comment: Even though Kevin B gave me a short version of the answer i needed, I am marking this answer as the solution. I am on my 3rd lesson, and already leaned a bunch of things i really needed to know about, but did not. Thank you. Really appreciate this URL.

Comment: @solefald I found it probably a week after it was published on pluralsight, and started watching about week ago, I just loved it myself.

Comment: @JohnPapa I did indeed. Moreover we grasp a lot of things from it to several projects we are working on.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are creating something like a single load web application. I'll start with a warning. Creating a single load web application is much harder than a normal web application. (in which you would be going to new pages, which reload the browser window). You actually have to be very careful with events you attach and objects you create, because they won't go away, since you never go to another page, you'll need to throw away the things you're done with. Even developers with a lot of experience struggle with single load web applications.

That said, if you're working heavily in javascript, and you make some changes to a script file and want to see the affect, you can make a function in your application (or use console in chrome) to give you the ability to reload your script files. Basically, write a function which appends the script file you ask it to, this will reload the code in that file, and you don't have to reload the page. In chromes console, you can execute javascript directly against the page, if you execute a function definition that already exists, it is overwritten. I do this all the time to debug issues.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. I've been struggling with things that never go away, or come in doubles when you only expect a single one. I guess I can split it in pages, but I hate page reloading. Plus lots of content (like a pretty large dynamic side navigation) will have to be duplicated, which means additional database calls, and network traffic.

Comment: Not everything has to be a page reload. But, some things you might want to make new pages. Really when your implementing a feature, think about weather it should be a new page, or if it would be better accomplished with ajax and javascript.